# Spring jdbctemplate is it required to close the connection

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

I am fetching the connection in jdbctemplate in below fashion:-

```
getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource().getConnection()
```

Is it necessary to close the connection fetched in the above manner? The spring JDBCTemplate API states that connection closures will be handled automatically , so I am not sure if this is happening correctly.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html

Comment: That code is wrong. Why are you doing that, when using `JdbcTemplate` you shouldn't be messing around with the connection yourself, use the template, you are working against it instead of using it.

Comment: This is the old code and it has connection leakage issues which I need to debug.

Comment: As stated the code is wrong. If you are messing around with the connection yourself then you need to close it. Either rewrite the code to correctly use the `JdbcTemplate` or do the old try/catch/finally for resource management which in turn beats the whole purpose of having a `JdbcTemplate` present at all. You aren't using the template ...

Comment: For connection leaks it's the datasource , connection pool configurations that need to be looked into. Suspect the problem could be in that, as far closing connection programmatically via jdbcTemplate that may not be necessary.

Comment: No he isn't using the `JdbcTemplate`... He is having a highly complex way of obtaining the datasource to open a connection. Basically pening connections and thus you must manage it.

Comment: Hi Deinum, I agree that the process used is complex and not correct, and after debugging i find your statement correct that if the connection is used in this fashion then we need to close it explicitly.

Comment: Well after 12 years of spring, teaching and consulting spring and written books about it I kind of know what I'm saying :). But as stated your code is wrong and you shouldn't use it like that. Instead of getting the connection, wrap the code in a `ConnectionCallback` and call the `execute` method on the `JdbcTemplate` that way the template will take care of all complexity for you.

Answer (score 2):

When you are obtaining the `DataSource` from the `JdbcTemplate` and use that to obtain a `Connection` you are basically completely bypassing the `JdbcTemplate`. You now have a very complex way of obtaining a new `Connection`. Because this connection isn't managed by Spring but yourself you also need to close it and apply exception handling.

It is better to use the [`ConnectionCallback`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/ConnectionCallback.html) instead to get a `Connection`. The `JdbcTemplate` will then manage the `Connection` and do all resource handling.

```
getJdbcTemplate().execute(new ConnectionCallback<Void>() {
    public Void doInConnection(Connection conn) {
        // Your JDBC code here.
    }
});
```

It would even better to use one of the other `JdbcTemplate` methods and write proper code which would save you from messing with plain JDBC code at all.

Comment: Can we use it in spring bppt 2.0.2 version.