# Why would I get "Connection is not available" from Hikari Pool when database server is clearly not busy and I am properly closing all connections?

Tags: postgresql, hikaricp

I'm getting this exception in production. Things are quiet for weeks at a time and then we get a "rash" of them all of a sudden:

> Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException:
> Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is
> java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is
> not available, request timed out after 1031ms.

**STEPS TAKEN TO INVESTIGATE THE PROBLEM:**

This symptom has well-known possible causes, which I have checked:

- `JdbcTemplate` is being used correctly, checked: [Spring jdbctemplate is it required to close the connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34650653/spring-jdbctemplate-is-it-required-to-close-the-connection)
- Using try-with-resource to ensure Connections are closed, checked: [Hikari Pool Connection is not available Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66920429/hikari-pool-connection-is-not-available-error)
- Database server can support the load, checked (server not busy at all, checked `top` and `pg_activity` and `netstat` -- really not much is going on): [Hikari connection pool, Connection is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46888512/hikari-connection-pool-connection-is-not-available)

What else could be causing this?

*Configuration*

```
<bean id="listingDataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="myserver:5432/mydata?reWriteBatchedInserts=true" />
    <property name="username" value="${username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${password}" />
    <property name="minimumIdle" value="1" />
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="${10}" />
    <property name="connectionTimeout" value="1000" />
    <property name="leakDetectionThreshold" value="60000" />
    <property name="idleTimeout" value="120000" />
    <property name="maxLifetime" value="300000" />
</bean>
```

Comment: add your configuration (do you use idle?), also there could be issue if you are using also other pool as PgBouncer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57756239/not-able-to-open-connection-from-pgbouncer-connection-attempt-timed-out/57756405#57756405

Comment: Configuration added!

Comment: Do you have leak warnings? Did you tried removing idle settings?

Comment: There are no leak warnings. I did not try removing idle... that would increase the number of connections, I think.